# Can a consumable inapp purchase be verified after it is consumed

Tags: in-app-billing

The documentation states all inapp products are managed now. However, you must still make a distinction of whether your inapp product is managed or not when you set it up, so it appears there is still a difference. Thus I've been setting up consumable products as unmanaged.

I've set up the "getpurchase" and "verifydeveloperpayload" function for each item to check whether anything has been bought. I'm assuming this would return false for a consumed consumable, since otherwise you call the consume function. Would using the "getpurchase" function for each item and checking if it is null be enough?

It would be nice to be able to check whether a game app player has bought anything, consumable (unmanaged?) or otherwise (managed), in order to eliminate ads for that player.

Comment: I don’t have experience using it, but check out “[Receipt Validation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/releasenotes/General/ValidateAppStoreReceipt/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010573-CH105-SW1)” in the iOS docs. It appears that *every* IAP can result in a receipt.